# pdfMake createPdf html2canvas: empty pages if content is more than 2 pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pdf, pdfmake

I am trying to create a PDF from a large (~500 rows) HTML table. However, the PDF is generated with blank pages (except the logo which is on top of first page). How I can fix that?

Here is my code:

```
<button id="btnExportCat">Export PDF</button>

    <script>
        jQuery("body").on("click", "#btnExportCat", function () {
            //get the details
        html2canvas(jQuery("#catalog_table")[0], {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                var docDefinition = {
                    pageSize: "A4",
                    content: [{
                        image: "data:image/png;base64,....logo_image_base64_encrypted_code....",
                        width: 80,
                        alignment: "center"
                    },
                    {
                        image: data,
                        width: 500,
                        height: "auto"
                    }]
                };
               pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("catalogue.pdf");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: You could do it without html2canvas, pdfMake has table option to add multiple rows.
You could save your data as json string, onclick parse that data and generate pdf

Comment: @AkramHossain How I can do this? can you share an example please?

Comment: Check this http://pdfmake.org/playground.html